# How to Stop Recursive Call Of Handler?

Tags: java, android, handler

I created a handler, to imitate timer task. 
because TimerTask was acting differently on different tablets.
so I created this handler method.
in timer there was a method `timerTask.cancel();`
but how to stop this handler
it keeps on running even after the application is exited.
as you can see logs running even after back press.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

public void recursivelycallHandler(){
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d("handler is running", "true" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            recursivelycallHandler();

        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: while you want to stop it ? I mean any condition ?

Comment: If you want to stop only at when the app is getting close then just put the override method onDestroy and at that time remove the callback of the handler. If you still not get solution then let me comment which difficulty you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 methods to do that ..

```
handler.removeCallbacks(Runnable r);
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
handler.removeMessages(int what)
```

In your case first two seem feasible .. add any of the above method  in ondestroy or on a listener to backpress..

Comment: this worked... thanks... will accept your answer in 5 mins as stackoverflow is not letting me to do so rt now

Answer (score 1):

By putting any condition

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int i = 0;
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d("handler is running", "true" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            if(i>5)
               handler.removeCallback(myRunnable);
            else{
                i++;
                handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 100); // here is self calling
            }

        }
    };
}
handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 100);
```

Its recursive method but you can call the same Runnable object in run() instead of recursive method and remove that object when based on specific situation/condition

Answer (score 0):

You can store flag (boolean var) to detect if you need to call for your handler and before exit app change this flag to false and stop calling handler.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this below:

```
   public void recursivelycallHandler(){
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d("handler is running", "true" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            if(YOUR_CONDITION){
               recursivelycallHandler();
            }

        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Hope you got my point.

feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

just add isFinished to your run method:

```
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isFinished())
               return;
        Log.d("handler is running", "true" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        recursivelycallHandler();

    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: I will suggest to invoke removeCallback in order to avoid leaks